# Is there a specific way one should auto renew Lets Encrypt certs?

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, lets-encrypt

I am trying the following:

```
[~/letsencrypt]# ./certbot-auto renew

No renewals were attempted.


[~/letsencrypt]# ./certbot-auto renew --force-renewal

No renewals were attempted.
```

However, I have had no success with either of these.

The server is running Apache.

Comment: Try adding `--force-renewal` at the end of the command.

Comment: do you have any accounts in your LE config directories? I assume you are running this on the box you used to create the certs

Answer (score 0):

This command checks all of the certificates that you’ve obtained and tries to renew any that will expire in less than 30 days.

So, in your case, all of your certificate is good enough and don't need to be renewed at that time.